# HTML in Android seems not working

Tags: java, android, html, textview

I want customize a string with results that will be written in a `TextView` but not works. I just want color some part of text  using html tags but it's still all text with same color. This is what i wrote so far:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return (Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#e61624\">"+fromHour+"</font>")) + " " + from + " / " + toHour + " " + to;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: "Seems not to work", but what does it currently display?

Comment: I wrote what display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use `Html.fromHtml` inside the `toString()` method.

In `toString()`, simply return the corresponding text:

```
return "<font color=\"#e61624\">"+fromHour+"</font> " + from + " / " + toHour + " " + to;
```

Then call:

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(yourObject.toString());
```

Comment: Do you mean without brackets? Nope, now i try thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
// Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.

yourTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#e61624\">"+fromHour+"</font>  " + from + " / " + toHour + " " + to));
```

Comment: Nope :( .. This string for real i have to put it in a listview.. I think the best way to do what i want it's create a custom adapter right? With all items separated.

Answer (score 0):

```
String text = "<font color=\"#e61624\">"+"<small>" + "Hello"
                        + "</small>"+"</font>";         
    Html.fromHtml(text);
```